# SQL, DISTINCT product_id, orderQuantity

Tags: sql

Here is the given question:

Show me a list of the product codes along with the number of times that each code has been ordered (note, order quantity does affect the number of total times ordered); only include product codes that have been ordered at least once?

I have tried the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT productId, orderQuantity 
FROM Order
WHERE (orderQuantity > 0);
```

The table comes up with duplicate product ids. How do I get a table of distinct product ids with the SUM of their order quantities?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT productID, SUM(orderQuantity)
FROM Order
WHERE orderQuantity > 0
GROUP BY productID
```

You have to use an aggregate function, in this case `SUM()`, to have the sum of your quantities and you want the sums to be grouped by each product, in your case `productID`.

To understand how this works, just try removing the `GROUP BY` statement and the `productID` from the SELECT statement and the query will return the SUM of all quantities.

```
SELECT SUM(orderQuantity)
FROM Order
WHERE orderQuantity > 0
```

Then, if you add just the `GROUP BY productID` you will get the sum of quantities ordered for each product.

```
SELECT SUM(orderQuantity)
FROM Order
WHERE orderQuantity > 0
GROUP BY productID
```

Then just add the `productID` back in the SELECT statement to understand the information displayed.